# Can the Facebook like plugin share a link and join a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am adding the Facebook like plugin onto my website, and from what I understand, when a user clicks 'like' the URL of the current page or a specified page is posted on their wall.

Is it possible to have them join a Facebook page at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) plugin is for adding external pages to the [Social Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). If you want to have users Like your actual Facebook page from your external Web site, then the plugin you're looking for is the [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). You can customise various elements of it to add/remove features such as a live feed of your page or a facepile of people who like you page etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* that this is possible. Have a separate Like Plugin for your Facebook Page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  The `Like` feature you add to your website is for a specified `URL` for the user to `Like`.  The Facebook `Like` is for the Facebook page only.  You can't automatically get a webpage outside of Facebook to `Like` a Facebook page.  If this was possible, it would be an abuse to their system.